# Format each line of Word document output from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to format a word document report with data from a userform in Excel. I am attempting to format each line individually like it is HTML and I know I am doing it wrong. I will paste my code below, please guide me in the right direction on how to format each line just the way I want it. This selection of code should have the words Safety Observations: in bold and underlined, then the next line should be values from the text box, not bold or underlined. When I run the code I am just getting a plain text nonformatted version of this

```
    With wrdDoc
    .Content.Font.Bold = True
    .Content.Font.Underline = True
    .Content.InsertAfter ("Safety Observations:" & vbNewLine)
    .Content.Font.Bold = False
    .Content.Font.Underline = False
    .Content.InsertAfter (EOS.txtSafety & vbNewLine)
    End with
```

Comment: Have you used the built-in [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-cd56fb86-d8b2-475c-ba39-9728389feeeb?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1)?  This is a great way to discover what parts of the Word object model do what.  Try manually editing a word document, while running the recorder.  You can then transfer that code to Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the range in a variable can make it easier:

```
' optional early binding if reference is added to Microsoft Word #.0 Object Library
Dim r As Word.Range, wrdDoc As Word.Document 

Set r = wrdDoc.Paragraphs.Add.Range
r.InsertBefore "Safety Observations:"
r.Bold = True
r.Underline = True

wrdDoc.Paragraphs.Add.Range.InsertBefore EOS.txtSafety
```